# Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: symbol

Tags: reactjs, webpack, lazy-loading

I'm trying to use `lazy Loading` for my app.

**index.js**

```
import React, { Suspense , lazy , Component } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import 'index.scss';
import SomeComponent from './someComponent.js';
import * as serviceWorker from 'serviceWorker';

ReactDOM.render(<SomeComponent />, document.getElementById('root'));
serviceWorker.unregister();
```

**some component index.js file**

```
import React, { Suspense , lazy , Component } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
const Header = lazy(() => import('./_header'));

class SomeComponent extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <BrowserRouter>
          <React.Fragment>
            <Suspense>
              <Header />
            </Suspense>
          </React.Fragment>
      </BrowserRouter>
    );
  }
}

export default SomeComponent;
```

**header index.js file**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './index.scss';

class Header extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <h1>Header</h1>
        );
    }
}
export default Header;
```

But I've got this error:

Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: symbol.

My react version is **v16.6.3**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Suspense and lazy` are reachable in the following versions :

```
"react": "^16.6.3"
"react-dom": "^16.6.3"
```

This error relates to the `react-dom` which was not upgraded correctly!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a very simple example that should work using similar dependencies.

[image: Edit lazy-header]

I would recommend ensuring that `import('./_header')` resolves to the correct module, to check again that there is a default export and that it is a React component type. Additionally, make sure `{ fallback }` for the suspense component is a component type as well.

Comment: I added Fall back but I still get the same error. I think maybe that's because of the react upgrade . I've tested this on a new app and it works fine. But on my current project it causes this error.

Comment: As I shared the code my Header is a react class base component and it exports default ! what's wrong with that ?

Comment: Is this note related to this failure  ? 


    Note:

    React.lazy() and <React.Suspense> are not yet supported by ReactDOMServer. This is a known limitation that will be resolved in the future.

Comment: Yes, `<React.Suspense>` doesn't work with `renderToString` from `react-dom/server` (SSR), but it would seem you're getting some different kind of error. Your example seems just fine, so must be some small detail being overlooked .

Comment: I've found the issue ! The react-dom was not in the proper version so I've updated it to 16.6.3 and some other dependencies. I've thought by upgrading the react other dependencies will be upgraded but wrong ! Thanks a lot BTW :)